# Propene react with ICl

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry, polarity, chirality

When propene react with ICl , it gives an inoptically active compound ,why.

According to me there is chiral carbon so it should be optically active[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product is optically active compound. However reaction is not stereoselective and therefore both stereoisomers are formed without one being in excess to the other. Product is a racemic mixture of both isomers and therefore should not expose optical activity because effects of both isomers just cancel out.

Reagents or substrate must be optically active in first place in order to get optically active mixture of products.